# Can you display/change a message on the Windows 10 "change password" screen?

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, password-management

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the error messages displayed to users when changing their password? Specifically the complexity requires message. If possible I would like to change it to contain a little more detail for our students. Alternatively, displaying a message on the change password screen would also work.

I'm aware of the interactive logon GP options and the ability to change the login or desktop background but they don't really satisfy what I'm looking for.